# In Github actions, in an expression is there a way to determine what path/directory was pushed/committed to?

Tags: github-actions

Within a single Github action script, I'm looking to differentiate between commits on 2 different paths/directories. The below script is essentially what I'm trying to do. What I'm unsure about is how to determine the path committed to within an expression. For now I have **github.event.path** but that's probably wrong.

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
    paths: 
      - 'Path1/**'
      - 'Path2/**'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: do something when Path1 directory has a commit
        if: github.event.path == 'Path1/**'
        run: <do something>
      - name: do something when Path2 directory has a commit
        if: github.event.path == 'Path2/**'
        run: <do something else>
```

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend using the [path-filter action](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter). It enables conditional execution of workflow steps and jobs, based on the files modified by pull request, on a feature branch, or by the recently pushed commits.

**Here is an example of how it would look in your case:**

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
      id: filter
      with:
        filters: |
          path1:
            - 'Path1/**'
          path2:
            - 'Path2/**'

    # run only if 'path1' files were changed
    - name: path1 tests
      if: steps.filter.outputs.path1 == 'true'
      run: ...

    # run only if 'path2' files were changed
    - name: path2 tests
      if: steps.filter.outputs.path2 == 'true'
      run: ...

    # run if 'path1' or 'path2' files were changed
    - name: both paths tests
      if: steps.filter.outputs.path1 == 'true' || steps.filter.outputs.path2 == 'true'
      run: ...
```

There are also different examples on the action [README file](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter#conditional-execution) if you want to take a look.

Comment: Awesome, this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: dorny pluging worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with that is to use of the existing actions in the Marketplace.

https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files

Natively GitHub doesn't give you a solution directly for what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Github action workflow information is stored in [contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts). You can actually use the script given [here](https://til.simonwillison.net/github-actions/dump-context) to help you with create the `if` [conditionals](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions).

Comment: Have you tried analyzing context? I dumped the contents of every context and none of them contain path/dir info of the committed objects.